# D3.js loses object reference in "on" events

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need some help in understanding what's happening in my little code. In my webapp I use D3.js to draw some shapes that I call **markers**. A marker can be dragged over the screen and on every drag I take its position, do some computations and I update the data object that is assigned to this marker. Let me show you:

```
class Marker {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.computedStuff = 0;
  }

  getDisplayName() {
    return 'Marker ' + this.name;
  }
}

this.markerValues = {
  'm1': new Marker('m1'),
  'm2': new Marker('m2')
}

this.svg.selectAll('g.marker')
        .data(_.values(this.markerValues))
        .join(enter => {
          const group = enter.append('g');

          group.append('path')
              .attr('d', 'M -12.867771,6.1070093 V 13.761566 H 12.867771 '
                  + 'V 6.1070093 H 6.4338855 '
                  + 'L 0,-1.1321257 -6.4338856,6.1070093 Z')
              .attr('transform', `translate(0 120) scale(2)`)
              .attr('stroke', 'black')
              .attr('stroke-width', '1px')
              .attr('fill', '#fff')
              .on('dblclick', d => console.log(d));

          group.append('text')
              .attr('y', 120)
              .text(d => d.getDisplayName())
              .style('font-size', '10px')
              .style('fill', 'black');

          return group;
        })
        .attr('class', 'marker')
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on('drag', function (d) {
              // Computation here

              d.computedStuff = computedAbove;

              // Here is a typical code for moving a marker according to 
              // d3.event.
            })
        );
```

The problem lays in this: `.on('dblclick', d => console.log(d));`. This looks pretty straightforward – on double click, log the data content; and it "works" good until I move the marker. When the marker is moved, the `computedStuff` variable is changed due to computations, but subsequent double clicks on path logs old value in console as if the object was not changed at all. I'm 100% sure it has changed because I checked content of `this.markerValues` object. It looks as if the event handler has been attached a copy of the object and it logs the copy instead of the original object.

But...

When I remove this event handler from path and attach it to the group: `group.on('dblclick', d => console.log(d));`, then it works! I can move the marker, double click it and I'm always provided with a valid value.

Why is the group handler always provided with a valid data, whereas handler attached to a child of the group keeps some kind of a copy or unreferenced object?

Comment: I've reread the question and understand the error in my original answer (i blame sleep :( )  Try attaching your `dblclick` handler in an `update` function.  You're changing the data after rendering in `enter`.  The changed data hasn't been attached to the nodes because you haven't merged.

Comment: That is an interesting question. It **should** work, because the data is propagated to the children selections, ad attaching the event to the group or to the path should not make any difference. That said, I suggest you create an [MCVE], so we can check what's happening. I suspect the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

The simple solution is:  don't use the fat arrow `.on('dblclick', d => console.log(d));`

Use classical notation instead

```
.on('dblclick', function(d) { console.log(d) });
```

d3 sets the scope of `this` in the handler to refer to the referenced node.  Using fat arrows overrides the lexical scope.

However, you can use fat arrows in your handler if you use the full handler signature and reference the current nodes by index:

```
selection.on('dblclick', (d, i, nodes) => {
  console.log(nodes[i])
});
```

There is a decent explanation in [this article](https://medium.com/@yonester/on-d3-and-arrow-functions-b6559c1cebb8)

Comment: I'm not interested in nodes in my case, I reference a **data** entry. Your solution is for cases where someone has troubles with `this`. Data (`d`) is not affected by arrow functions.